# Word/Phrase that portrays fear and wonder/beauty

Tags: synonyms

I guess I need some rep to be here. I'm searching for a word/phrase that depicts the feeling of fear and attraction.  I'm thinking along the lines of awe-inspiring, dumbfounded, mystified ... I want to represent the overwhelming experience of insignificance and allure.

Comment: Are you looking for an adjective to describe the thing that inspired awe/fear (e.g. awe-inspiring, impressive), or for the person who is feeling the awe/fear (e.g. awed, impressed)?

Comment: My own thought is that you are attempting to express too much with one word. 'Awe' can convey both wonder and fearfulness but using the word on its own is insufficient. A writer must provide context and further expression to fully convey concept.

Comment: True, I should focus on creating emotion in the reader over giving them the emotion